# Iframe auto fullscreen makes status bar disappear

Tags: ios, swift

I display youtube videos (and other type of videos like dailymotion) from a UIWebView by loading an iFrame into it.

Here is the iFrame String:

```
let iFrameHtmlString = String(format:"<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"100%%\" height=\"300\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?autoplay=1\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>", youtubeId)
```

I load it into the UIWebView with:

```
webView.loadHTMLString("<body>" + iFrameHtmlString + "</body>", baseURL: nil)
```

- When I click on the video, the video launches in fullscreen.
- Then I rotate the device in landscape mode
- Then I rotate back the device in portrait mode
- Then I leave the fullscreen mode

=> My status bar has disappeared and won't appear until I kill the app and restart it.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Do you have a bit more code showing constraints or frames, or maybe what you have if you use the same UIWebView displaying a normal web page?

Comment: I'm not sure the way iFrame work with the UIWebView, but there is not much more code to see. The UIView itself is working fine I can rotate the screen and back without any trouble.
When you click on the frame on the UIWebView, it launches something that looks like a ViewController in fullscreen. I guess the problem comes from there but I don't control this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved it setting the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to YES (which was NO before), and thus the status bar appearance is not impacted by the full screen view controller that the iFrame shows.

Comment: but this cause status bar to be black always... I can't make white

Comment: If you use a UINavigationController with a navbar, use navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white, and maybe navigationBar.isTranslucent = false.

If not, the problem may be somewhere else.